# Reading file and getting values from a file. It shows only first one and others are empty

Tags: python-3.x

I am reading a file by using a with open in python and then do all other operation in the with a loop. While calling the function, I can print only the first operation inside the loop, while others are empty. I can do this by using another approach such as readlines, but I did not find why this does not work. I thought the reason might be closing the file, but with open take care of it. Could anyone please suggest me what's wrong

```
def read_datafile(filename):
     with open(filename, 'r') as f:
            a = [lines.split("\n")[0] for number, lines in enumerate(f) if number ==2]
            b = [lines.split("\n")[0] for number, lines in enumerate(f) if number ==3]
            c = [lines.split("\n")[0] for number, lines in enumerate(f) if number ==2]
     return a, b, c

read_datafile('data_file_name')
```

I only get values for a and all others are empty. When 'a' is commented​, I get value for b and others are empty.

**Updates**
The file looks like this:

```
 -0.6908270760153553 -0.4493128078936575  0.5090918714784820
  0.6908270760153551 -0.2172871921063448  0.5090918714784820
 -0.0000000000000000  0.6666999999999987  0.4597549674638203
  0.3097856229862140 -0.1259623621214220  0.5475896447896115
  0.6902143770137859  0.4593623621214192  0.5475896447896115
```

Comment: Can you paste the file (or something similar) that you are reading?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The construct

```
with open(filename) as handle:
    a = [line for line in handle if condition]
    b = [line for line in handle]
```

will always return an empty `b` because the iterator in `a` already consumed all the data from the open filehandle. Once you reach the end of a stream, additional attempts to read anything will simply return nothing.

If the input is seekable, you can rewind it and read all the same lines again; or you can `close` it (explicitly, or implicitly by leaving the `with` block) and open it again - but a much more efficient solution is to read it just once, and pick the lines you actually want from memory. Remember that reading a byte off a disk can easily take several orders of magnitude more time than reading a byte from memory. And keep in mind that the data you read could come from a source which is not seekable, such as standard output from another process, or a client on the other side of a network connection.

```
 def read_datafile(filename):
     with open(filename, 'r') as f:
         lines = [line for line in f]
     a = lines[2]
     b = lines[3]
     c = lines[2]
     return a, b, c
```

If the file could be too large to fit into memory at once, you end up with a different set of problems. Perhaps in this scenario, where you only seem to want a few lines from the beginning, only read that many lines into memory in the first place.

Comment: Perhaps also remember that `enumerate` starts from zero; if you genuinely want the second line, that's `lines[1]`.

Comment: Thank you so much for such a nice explanation, helped me to understand the problem and dig dipper.

Answer (score 0):

What exactly are you trying to do with this script? The `lines` variable here may not contain what you want: it will contain a single line because the file gets enumerated by lines.

Comment: I am trying to get  'a' as line number 2 in the file, 'b' as line number 3 and so on.

Comment: Hi Everett, as I am enumerating the lines again and again, shouldn't it be returning such values? I know this is not a good way to do but wanted to know what is the reason for returning 'a' but 'b' and 'c' as empty.

Comment: Something like this will return a list of tuples where each tuple contains 2 items: the line index (starting with zero) and the contents of the line:

```
    def read_datafile(filename):
         with open(filename, 'r') as f:
             return list(enumerate(f))
```